# If $X_0$ is a nontrivial solution to AX=0 and $X_1$ does not equal $X_0$ is a nontrivial solution to BX=0, then A+B is not invertible.

Tags: linear-algebra

If $x_0$ is a nontrivial solution to $Ax=0$ and $x_1$ does not equal $x_0$ is a nontrivial solution to $Bx=0$, then $A+B$ is not invertible.

I'm not understanding why this is false. Does anyone have a example showing why it is false?

Answer (score 3):

Take $$A=\begin{bmatrix}1&0\\0&0\end{bmatrix},\ \ \ B=\begin{bmatrix}0&0\\0&1\end{bmatrix},\ \ \ x_0=\begin{bmatrix}0\\1\end{bmatrix},\ \ \ x_1=\begin{bmatrix}1\\0\end{bmatrix}.
$$
Then $Ax_0=0$, $Bx_1=0$, but $A+B=I_2$ is invertible.